# how do I get the class that an object is being accessed from in java?

Tags: java

```
public class object0{
    Object classBeingAccessedFrom = ?;

    public static void getNumber(){
        return classBeingAccessedFrom.width/classBeingAccessedFrom.height;
    }
}
public class object1{
    public static int width = 500;
    public static int height = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(object0.getNumber());
    }
}
public class object2{
    public static int width = 400;
    public static int height = 600; 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(object0.getNumber());
    }

}
```

is it possible to be able to tell what class an object is being accessed from?
When I was working on making a easy to use vector3f class, I needed a way to be able to perceive what width and height the screen was for the perspective projection. Is there was a way to some how tell what the class was that is accessing the vector3f object, this would solve the problem.

Comment: Add the object as parameter and do not try to get it at this way

Comment: just change the method getNumber() to getNumber(int width, int height).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:

```
public class object0{

    public static void getNumber(int width, int height){
        return width/height;
    }
}
public class object1{
    public static int width = 500;
    public static int height = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(object0.getNumber(width, height));
    }
}
public class object2{
    public static int width = 400;
    public static int height = 600; 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(object0.getNumber(width, height));
    }

}
```